# Which custom post type does the current post belong to?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have looked all over the Codex and searched the web and I cannot find a way to accomplish what I am trying to do. All I need to do is display what CPT a post belongs to. For instance, I have two different post types, Courses and Resources, and I need a way to output which one of these a particular post belongs to. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) should do what you're asking.

Comment: Wow... I should either sleep or quit my job. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly access the [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects inside the loop. The current post `post_type` can be displayed with

```
echo $post->post_type;
```

**EDIT**

After some constructive comments to this answer (thank you @ialocin), I felt that it would really be beneficial to extend to my answer and shed some more light on this issue for future reference

You need to first look at the source code of `get_post_type()`

```
1121    /**
1122     * Retrieve the post type of the current post or of a given post.
1123     *
1124     * @since 2.1.0
1125     *
1126     * @param int|WP_Post $post Optional. Post ID or post object. Default is global $post.
1127     * @return string|bool Post type on success, false on failure.
1128     */
1129    function get_post_type( $post = null ) {
1130            if ( $post = get_post( $post ) )
1131                    return $post->post_type;
1132    
1133            return false;
1134    }
```

As one can see from the source of [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type), it is simply just a wrapper for `$post->post_type`. There is absolutely no impact on time or DB calls from the use of any of the two methods. As @PatJ stated in a comment, 6 of one and half dozen of the other.

The advantage however from using `get_post_type()` is that you can get the post type from any post outside the loop by passing any post ID to it. In this case it will use `get_post` to retrieve the post type from the post which is given. This is also very efficient and not resource intensive.

Here is the test result from that to state my point. My post ID is `159`

```
echo get_post_type(159);
```

gives a test result of

> 1 queries in 0.00098 seconds.

Comment: Which, getting the post type from a post type object, pretty much is what `get_post_type()` does.

Comment: That works too. The only advantage to `get_post_type()`, I suppose, is that you can use it *outside* The Loop. But the OP's question seems to take place inside The Loop, so in this case it's six of one.

Comment: @ialocin jip. It is like Pat also said 6 of one and a half dozen of the other. I always use the `WP_Post` objects like `ID` and `post_type` inside the loop directly. Personal preference :-)

Comment: You know, I barely added the information for you as respondent, as I'm pretty certain you already knew, more as additional information for others, so that they can connect some dots, if they come to this and if they want to.

Comment: Thanks for that @ialocin :-). Totally misunderstood your intensions here, crap. Should avoid answering comments early morning, hahaha. No harm done or intended. :-)

Comment: Haha, not a problem at all. Just for future reference - because I have the feeling it will happen again, as I tend to sometimes just add information pieces, if I feel they could be helpful - if I'm not saying »why not do/better do/I don't like« or »awesome/I like/this can be added to make it better«, then it is just an additional information.

Comment: @ialocin You have a valid point there. I have updated my post accordingly. Sometimes we take such extras for granted , not thinking about others that might not know this much as we do. And you are correct in stating that this **will** come up again someday.

Comment: I would give you another upvote for the effort, but of course I can't. And, yes, it will come up and we always forget.